# Pass variable in image url

Tags: javascript, css

```
var a = "C:/xyz/ABC/mno/abc.jpg";
```

I want to pass this veriable inside:

```
$('.abc').css( "background-image", "url(a)");
```

Its not working how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You are quite close, you just need to break out of the double quotes for your `background-image` and use string concatenation to apply the `a` variable:

```
$('.abc').css( "background-image", "url(" + a + ")");
```

Comment: Probably because you're trying to use a `file://` URL, try putting the image in or near the same folder as the HTML file and using a relative URL instead (e.g. `var a = 'images/ABC.jpg';`)

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = "url(" +'\"'+  a +'\"'+ ")";
$('.abc').css("background-image", b);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Are you kidding? `$('.abc').css("background-image",'url('+a+')')`

Comment: A little less attitude and more explanation might get you some upvotes.